# What should I do with chi-square expected values below in this large table?

Tags: chi-squared-test, spss

I asked a question about emotions felt during a particular period, taking the question from previous literature. However, for a number of frustrating reasons, I ended up with small sample size. I now want to bivariable relationships i.e. Chi-square. However, I'm getting a warning about expected values below 5 (given in green below) and from what I understand Fisher's Exact Test is n/a in this case. I'd really appreciate some advice to understand the relationship between these questions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do the rows not add up to the same total? Are the same people appearing in each row? What is your scientific question?

Comment: A chi-squared test is not going to help you understand relationships among these questions: it will only help you determine whether you should treat the two columns as reflecting two distinct sets of response tendencies.  You appear to have few data and they are inconsistent (or largely missing) as well, suggesting the software's warning was most helpful: you likely don't have enough data to determine much, if anything.

Comment: Are the emotions being mentioned mutually exclusive?  If not, a chi square test isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Above comments are true enough. It is the case however, that if you have the Exact Tests option, you can specify Exact or Monte Carlo results for chi-square tests in SPSS CROSSTABS with general RxC tables and get the Fisher-Freeman-Halton extension of the Fisher Exact Test.